# Can't find specific filters in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

Not sure how to word the question, but I'll try and explain in as much detail as possible. I'm trying to find out how many bytes of content are being returned to my browser but can't find the `Content-Length` line under the Hypertext Transfer Protocol section. Furthermore, I can't find the last time the file was modified. I'm using the most up-to-date version of Wireshark and haven't changed any settings or added/removed anything so I'm not sure why I'm not getting what I'm looking for.

[image: Wireshark]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Wireshark log indicates that you are getting a `304 Not Modified` response. In such case there is no body returned.

> 1.Any response message which "MUST NOT" include a message-body (such as the 1xx, 204, and 304 responses and any response to a HEAD request) is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields, regardless of the entity-header fields present in the message.

[RFV 2616 sec. 4.4](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4)

And no body thus no `Content-Length` header as it informs about the presence of the message body

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

[RFC 2616 sec. 14.13](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)

Comment: Is there anything I can do on my end to fix this issue or is it a server side issue?

Comment: @lb1021 you can force the browser not to use cache by issuing different url always by adding a different query string each time i.e. `?a=<random values>`

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go